# python take out portion of URL and keep original formatting

Tags: python, url, split

Lets say i have the following URL:

```
 https://espn.com/1234/44/222/mlb/standings
```

And i wanted to extract the `/1234/44/222` as is. I understand that `split('/')[3:5]` would extract that , but it would lose the / formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your urls follow the above format, and you want the text between `.com` and `/mlb`, you can use the following regular expression:

[`.com([\/\d]+)\/mlb`](https://regex101.com/r/vWUR3f/2)

In action:

```
>>> s = 'https://espn.com/1234/44/222/mlb/standings'
>>> re.findall(r'.com([\/\d]+)\/mlb', s)
['/1234/44/222']
```

You could also use `join` with `split`:

```
>>> '/'.join(s.split('/')[3:6])
1234/44/222
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without hardcoding the .com and mlb values as they might not be 100% consistent?

Comment: @skimchi1993 see my update.  It grabs regions of the url based on of indices, and maintains `/`

Comment: Glad to help, if this answered your question, check out [What to do if someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = "https://espn.com/1234/44/222/mlb/standings"
new_s = '/'.join(re.findall("\d+", s))
```

Output:

```
'1234/44/222'
```

Comment: is there a way to do this without hardcoding the .com and mlb values as they might not be 100% consistent?

Comment: still a little confused on who the "\d+" knows to only grab the integers?

Comment: @skimchi1993 It is part of the Python Regex [compiler process](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).

Comment: ah so you have to set to only digits. i was more interested in finding something that extracted a portion based off on index.